# SQL count occurrences of unique id on a specific date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Table example:

| unique ID | process date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1/1/2023 | 10 |
| 123 | 1/1/2023 | 15 |
| 123 | 1/1/2023 | 20 |
| 123 | 1/1/2023 | 16 |
| 123 | 1/1/2023 | 90 |
| 124 | 1/1/2023 | 11 |
| 124 | 1/1/2023 | 10 |
| 124 | 1/1/2023 | 15 |
| 124 | 1/1/2023 | 20 |
| 124 | 1/1/2023 | 16 |
| 124 | 1/1/2023 | 90 |
| 124 | 1/1/2023 | 11 |

I would like to count the amounts per unique ID per process date.

This is what I'd like the output to display:

| ID | process date | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1/1/2023 | 5 |
| 124 | 1/1/2023 | 7 |

Nothing that I have tried works.

Comment: Do show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to GROUP BY both columns

```
SELECT
   ID,  process,    COUNT(Amount) count_amount
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID,    process
ORDER BY ID,    process
```